# replace fancybox close button with fontawesome

Tags: css, font-awesome, fancybox-2

Is it possible to do so? I tried to modified the css but couldn't make it work. The best thing that I could do is to replace the close button with color background which is not desirable result.

Answer (score 2):

**[RTFM](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)**: You have a kind of object in the JavaScript with various templates. You need to change that:

```
{
    wrap     : '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',
    image    : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />',
    iframe   : '<iframe id="fancybox-frame{rnd}" name="fancybox-frame{rnd}" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0"' + ($.browser.msie ? ' allowtransparency="true"' : '') + '></iframe>',
    error    : '<p class="fancybox-error">The requested content cannot be loaded.<br/>Please try again later.</p>',
    closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
    next     : '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
    prev     : '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
}
```

The `closeBtn` is what you wanna change.